# Code copied from google but I keep getting error and can't see why

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied some code from googling to resize a table but I keep getting an Invalid or Unqualified reference error but for life of me cannot see why...

```
Sub resize()

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Dim tblMSFT As ListObject
    
   '=====================================================================================
    ' Get work sheet
    Set wst = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    
    ' Get table
    Set tblMSFT = wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
   
'resize MasterSupplierTable


With Worksheets(wst).ListObjects(tblMSFT).resize.Range.resize(.Range.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - .Range.Row + 1)

End With

End Sub

'===========================================================================================================
'Code found through Google
'With Worksheets("Data Sorter").ListObjects("table1").resize .Range.resize(.Range.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - .Range.Row + 1)
'End With
'===========================================================================================================
```

Comment: worked out another way....'resize MasterSupplierTable
Dim Lastsheetrow As Long
Lastsheetrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

tblMSFT.resize Range("A1:O" & Lastsheetrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code to resize a table by adding e. g. 2 rows:

```
Sub ResizeListObject()
  Dim wst As Worksheet
  Set wst = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
  With wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    .Resize wst.Range(.Range.Cells(1), .Range.Cells(.Range.Cells.Count).Offset(2, 0))
  End With
End Sub
```

To resize the table onto the occupied cells on the worksheet use:

```
Sub ResizeListObject()
  With Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    .ListObjects("MSF_Table").Resize .UsedRange
  End With
End Sub
```